# Need help remembering a magic anime with a young girl and her pet

Tags: story-identification, anime

[image: Drawing of two anime characters]

I drew this when I was younger from the outro of a magic anime. Now I’m trying to figure out what anime it was.

Does anyone know what it is?

Comment: When did you watch this? Also, you might want to check out [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11874/21267) to see if you can remember anything else.

Comment: I know very little about anime but noticed this this in the Hot Network Questions feed, and was instantly thought, *"Ponyo!"*  ...but I suppose "young girl with her pet" probably describes several anime plots.  (I'm constantly quoting *Ponyo* characters to my son, most often trying to force him to ***"Revert!"** ...back into his cute pre-teenager days.)

Comment: Given how quickly this was correctly answered despite scarce written details, we should probably add _"draw it and include a picture"_ in the ID FAQ!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Could it be [Jewelpets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewelpet)?

[image: Miria, Akari, and Sara with their two Jewelpets]

It looks like you drew Akari Sakura and her rabbit Ruby.